# Notepad++ Function list not showing functions inside classes without indentation

Tags: notepad++

I've been trying to build a new function list parser in Notepad++ using the Ruby parser as a base, but ran into an issue where functions are not being picked up if they are not indented in a class.

For example, the following works as expected:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(breed, name)  
    # Instance variables  
    @breed = breed  
    @name = name  
  end;

  def bark  
    puts 'Ruff! Ruff!'  
  end;

  def display  
    puts "I am of #{@breed} breed and my name is #{@name}"  
  end;
end Dog;
```

and produces this function list:

[image: correct function list]

However, if we remove indentation:

```
class Dog
def initialize(breed, name)  
# Instance variables  
@breed = breed  
@name = name  
end;

def bark  
puts 'Ruff! Ruff!'  
end;

def display  
puts "I am of #{@breed} breed and my name is #{@name}"  
end;
end Dog;
```

We end off with this function list, where the class definition has been missed (I'm assuming because the functions inside the class are being ignored, so the empty class is not rendered):

[image: wrong function list]

I'm using the following parser:

```
<parser
    displayName="Ruby"
    id         ="ruby_function"
>
    <!-- within a class-->
    <classRange
        mainExpr    ="(?&lt;=^class\x20).*?(?=\n\S|\Z)"
    >
        <className>
            <nameExpr expr="\w+" />
        </className>
        <function
            mainExpr="^\s*def\s+\w+"
        >
            <functionName>
                <funcNameExpr expr="(?&lt;=def\s)\w+" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </classRange>
    <!-- without class-->
    <function
        mainExpr="^\s*def\s+\w+"
    >
        <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="(?&lt;=def\s)\w+" />
        </functionName>
    </function>
</parser>
```

I think the problem stems from the mainExpr for the classRange. Can anyone explain what can be changed in the parser so that the functions are correctly picked up regardless of whether they're indented or not?